# How to install gem to local path and then require it

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I want to setup gem from rubygems.org to some subfolder of my project like `"/gems"` and then use it from script via `require`. Please help me resolve it.

Comment: Why do you want to use a specific subfolder and not the default gem folder?

Comment: i've small script and i want to distribute it with gems

Comment: Usually you would declare such a dependency in the gem' `.gemspec`. Why is this not possible in your case?

Comment: can u give me some example of use gemspec file,
i'm try

 Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  s.require_paths = ['./gems']
end

Answer (score 0):

The preferred way is to go with a standard scenario: you build a `gem`, with binaries, pack it and when used it will download all the dependencies itself, according to `gemspec`. If the above is for some reason non-acceptable for you, one of the options would be:

• You create a `gem` for your script;

• You specify a [path where to install dependencies](http://bundler.io/v1.12/bundle_install.html):

```
bundle install --path=vendor/gems
```

• Instead of `require` you use `require_relative` in your script because on destination machines there won’t be local bundle’s config file, pointing to the right folder;

• As your script is finished, you pack everything including gems.

Answer (score 0):

The normal way to go in a ruby project is to setup a Gemfile and use [bundler (see link for more info)](http://bundler.io/) to handle the gems your project requires, without having to think of where they are stored

However, if there really is no way around shipping an own gem-directory, e.g. because your productive system has absolutely no way to access the internet, you could make it this way:

- Create a directory in the root of your project (e.g. 'gems').
- Download and unpack the gems to that directory (or use the appropriate options of `gem install` to redirect the installation into that directory)
- Create a ruby file in the root directory of your project with following constants:

  ```
  PROJECT_DIR = __dir__
  GEMS_DIR = File.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'gems')
  ```
- Now you can require your gems link `require File.join(GEMS_DIR, <gem_name>)`

Nonetheless, you should really think about using bundler, if possible in any way.

EDIT: to install gem via `gem install`

1. Delete the PG data from your project's `gems` directory
2. uninstall global gem `gem uninstall pg`
3. Install pg again, but into your project's directory: `gem install -i <path_to_projects_gems_dir> pg`
4. Run you script again with the require pointing to the gem stated above

Comment: http://oi64.tinypic.com/29zok0x.jpg - i try, but it not work for me.. I've got
/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- /home/ben/RubymineProjects/database_dumper/gems/pg-0.18.4.gem (LoadError)

Comment: i'm try to unpack gem via gem unpack and set path to ... lib/pg.rb.. it doesn't work

Comment: how did you install the gem into the directory? Have you unpacked it?

Comment: i just download gem file and copy it to gems folder, them i unpack this like that - " gem unpack pg.gem" and try to require this..
I cant understood why this don't work.

Comment: does `gem install pg` work on your machine? The gem contains C-extensions, not only plain ruby, and therefore requires to be built at first. Meaning, it's not that easy to simply port it via directory.

Comment: so, i run gem install pg as root, then my script work, well... it's a bit strange for me..

Comment: that's because you now have a global installation of `pg` that `require` can find. Your script is still NOT using the gem from your `/gems` directory. The the C-externsions of the gem need to be compiled first, which `gem install` does. 
I have added some further steps my post.

Comment: as i understood - gem install --local - is solution ?

Comment: it again doest work
require_relative File.join(GEMS_DIR, 'pg-0.18.4/lib/pg')

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this:

> gem install -i ./ pg

```
ROOT = File.expand_path('..', __FILE__)
ENV['GEM_PATH'] = File.join(ROOT, './')

require 'pg'
puts 'Version of libpg: ' + PG.library_version.to_s
```